5V on DP and DM pins on FT232RL?
Can I apply 5 volts to the DP and DM pins of the FT232RL, given that the technical sheet says that the maximum voltage of these pins is up to 3.8 volts?

You can do whatever you like but the manufacturer says max 3.8V, so if you exceed this, the manufacturer does not guarantee the device will work. What sort of answer do you want?

What exactly do you think "maximum voltage" means?

Can I apply 5 volts to the DP and DM pins can you give more info about the application? Why do you need to apply 5V to those pins?

Are you trying to work out if you've broken the IC after accidentally connecting the 5V, or something?

Why would you even apply 5V to DP and/or DN pins? What are you after by asking this question, as the way it is now asked does not make much sense.

It looks like you've already read the part of the datasheet that answers your question. Given that you already have the answer, I don't understand what additional information you're asking us for.

Short answer: No, you should not
Longer answer:
Sure you can do that. It might destroy your chip but that doesn't technically mean that you can't do it.
It's even written right there:

So: Don't do it.

"that DOESN'T technically mean..."

@Finbarr true. Fixed now :)
